# In Qt how to create GUI for user to input nxn matrix?

Tags: c++, qt, matrix

I am learning Qt please do not assume I know a lot I appreciate if you could help me with this.

I am working on an application for solving a linear system of equations. For that, I want to take input from user two matrices `A(nxn)` and `B(nx1)` solve them and then display the matrix `x(nx1)`.

I get the part of solving them, but in Qt I am finding it difficult to make the window that takes the input of matrices and shows the output.

How should I do that? Someone please help me with this.

Comment: It's Qt, not QT.

Comment: Is QGridLayout with QLineEdits good enough for you? For small n number (not a hundreds ofc) could be fine..

Comment: it will do ..what i want exactly is to first ask the value of n..then following that 
a nxn grid to get created where user can enter the values of elements in the matrix..but i don't know how to do that..i designed dialogue box for 3x3 but then what to do if the user wants to solve for 4x4 or 5x5 etc??

Answer (score 1):

Goto into Examples (Ctrl+1 in QtCreator) and look for [spreadsheet](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-spreadsheet-example.html).
Then configure and run that small project. A spreadsheet it's (albeit a bit overkill) a simple and efficient way to input (and output) matrices of any size and shape. Just apply your requirements about number of cols, rows and value constraints as you see fit.